# UILabel should produce ellipsis but doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, ellipsis

i've have a UITableView and the cell are populated by a post call to a remote service. 
I've set the UILabel lineBreakMode property to `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` and lines to 2. On the cell xib everything seems to be allright. here is the screenshots:

[image] [image]

this is the piece of code i use to populate the text after parsed the JSON retrieved from the remote service.

```
func  tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if (posts.count == 0){
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
                TableViewCellIdentifiers.emptyCell, for: indexPath)
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
                TableViewCellIdentifiers.postCell, for: indexPath) as! PostCell

            let post = posts[indexPath.row]
            cell.userNameLabel.text = post.userName
            cell.postTextLabel.text = post.text
            cell.timeLabel.text = post.time
            cell.distanceLabel.text = post.distance

            return cell
        }
    }
```

but here it is the result and it doesn't produce the ellipsis but every thing is overlying
[image]

Any idea where could the problem be?

Comment: Missing the constraint to tell your label that it can't exceed a certain width (like 8 points before Time label or distance label)? Also, you may also want to check the yellow warning about it's Y position or height, and see the result (fix it, and maybe add a schrink scale for the font size to fit)

Comment: The orange lines in xib mean there is something wrong. You are probably setting only the frame, not the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have missing constraints. Try to set a constraint from the right edge of the labels to the `Time` and `Distance` labels on the right. I would make all labels have a fixed width and set all constraints with relation `Equal`, the UILabels with align the text properly inside.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is because the width constraints you have given. The yellow warning indicate that at runtime Label width can exceed to any limit. Also the Y position or height is not set properly. You need to set these two constraints otherwise at runtime, `Label` will take the width that can fit the text length.